# Python 3: time.tzset() alternative for Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, datetime, timezone

I am new to Python. I am reading about dates and times from the lovely book 'Python 3 Standard Library by Example' by Doug Hellmann and I stumbled upon this code snippet:

```
import time
import os


def show_zone_info():
    print(f'''\
    TZ    : {os.environ.get('TZ', '(not set)')}
    tzname: {time.tzname}
    Zone  : {time.timezone} ({time.timezone / 3600})
    DST   : {time.daylight}
    Time  : {time.ctime()}
    ''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Default: ')
    show_zone_info()

    ZONES = [
        'GMT',
        'Europe/Amsterdam'
    ]

    for zone in ZONES:
        os.environ['TZ'] = zone
        # time.tzset()      # Only available on Unix
        print(zone, ':')
        show_zone_info()
```

Problem is, `time.tzset()` is only available on Unix and without it on Windows machine, timezone doesn't change during the run time of the code. What is the alternative to `time.tzset()` on Windows? (I am running Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10 at the time of asking this question.)

Comment: Have you looked at this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360981/make-python-respond-to-windows-timezone-changes

Comment: @avrsanjay, it doesn't work. At least I couldn't make it work. The solution responds to Windows timezone changes. I, on the other hand, am changing `os.environ['TZ']`. Besides, it looks like the solution is for Python2 written 9 years ago. I was wondering if there are any other possible solutions since then.

Comment: @MrFuppes, I have no problem with getting the timezone, I have a problem in setting the timezone.

Comment: @SagittariusAStar_MW, sorry, I totally misread this, apologies! Having a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzset), I see why the method could be useful but the docs also say that the function should not be relied on. I would definitely suggest to work with specified timezones instead of altering the behaviour of e.g. `localtime()` - I imagine this can create a total mess...

Comment: @MrFuppes, um, the note says that behavior changed by setting `os.environ['TZ']` should not be relied upon *without* calling `tzset()`. It doesn't exactly say `tzset()` is unreliable.
Testing out code under different timezone may be necessary for debugging.

Comment: @SagittariusAStar_MW: I mean, if you work with `datetime` objects (which rely on functions from the `time` module), it is just easier and more readable to explicitly specify the `tzinfo` property from my experience. But that may depend on the situation / the project you work on.

Comment: @MrFuppes, I understand. I will keep the question standing to see if anybody has any solution to this specific problem. Thanks.